# Exception ParseException is not compatible with throws clause in Comparator<L>.compare(L, L)

Tags: java

> Exception ParseException is not compatible with throws clause in Comparator.compare(L, L).

I am running on **java 6** so I have to implement Comparator and override the compare method and then make an object of that class. In compare, I have to parse the date using formatter, which may cause a `ParseException` and I am unable to throw it to the caller from the overridden compare.

Comment: can you post your code here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `compare` signature doesn't allow for checked `Exception`s.

```
int compare(T o1, T o2);
```

You'd say "*then I'll just wrap it in a `RuntimeException`*". Wait!

*JavaDoc* says

> Caution should be exercised when using a comparator capable of
>   imposing an ordering inconsistent with equals to order a sorted set
>   (or sorted map).

That means, do you throw the same `Exception` in the `equals` method?
If yes, than it's okay to do so in the `compare` method, otherwise, catch it and return an appropriate `integer` value.

Personally, I don't throw (manually) `Exception`s from ordering/equality methods, as I run data consistency checks when the objects gets created.

Comment: That's awesome. very explanatory. thank you for the answer :)

Comment: @benignfoppery consider accepting the answer if you feel it's worth it. Thanks!

Comment: Done. Was new to asking questions on stack so didn't know how to accept it.

Comment: @benignfoppery Thank you! Remember that you're not forced to accept, only when  the answer is good and sufficient to solve your doubts/problem. It's also an appreciation for the ones that answer ;)